# Same value in one column and the adjacent column cells have different values, How to put different values of the adjacent column in to a single row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Quesion: Input

```
    XXX      a   

    XXX      b

    XXX      c
```

I want the following OutPut

```
    XXX      a      b     c
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use this array formula (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together) below:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF($D1=$A$1:$A$10,ROW($B$1:$B$10),""),COLUMN()-COLUMN($D1)),1),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Get your list of unique values and then use:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$5)/($A$1:$A$5=$D1),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

Copy this over and down.

[image]